# Word to describe that task should happen in one way and one way only

Tags: adjectives

I'm looking for an adjective that describes that tasks should be approached "one-ly".

To give some context:

- [Task] must be performed in one way and exclusively one way.

or

- There must exist precisely one method of performing [task].

I am looking for an adjective that describes this "one-ness". The adjective does not need to specify what the method is, *it should merely prescribe that the task should be approached in precisely one way*.

The closest word I could think of is "uniform".

Comment: "precise" or  "specific", perhaps "very precise" or "very specific".

Answer (score 1):

there is only one way to do it and it's **"unique"** (meaning that it's specific for that situation only)

> - [**unique**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unique):  being the only one of its kind, characteristic only of a particular category or entity.

"Such weather pattern is unique to coastal areas."

"This is a unique opportunity."

"Humans are unique because they have the capacity to choose what they do."

" The area has its own unique language, Catalan."

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking of **unambiguous**. The Free Dictionary defines this as the opposite of:

> [Ambiguous: Open to more than one interpretation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ambiguous)

"Unambiguous" then should refer to the description of the task, not to the task itself.

Comment: It's not that the method could be ambiguous. It's that multiple methods could exist which could perform the task. My sentence prescribes that such a situation should not occur.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for an adjective that modifies *task* but refers to the *process* of performing the task. Hence terms such as *singular task* or *sole task* aren't what you're looking for.

A task can be described as [*prescribed*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prescribe?q=prescribed) (i.e. a prescribed task), but the term can be ambiguous - a *prescribed task* may be one whose *process* is fixed, but it could also be one whose *assignment* is fixed (i.e. it has been assigned to just one individual).

Since the task is specified in advance (or is as good as specified, since there's only one way it should be performed), you can say that it is a *programmed task*. The term *programmed* is defined as a verb, but here functions as an adjective since it modifies the noun *task*. Here's the dictionary entry (for the verb):

> **Program** *verb*
>   2 Arrange according to a plan or schedule
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/programme?q=programmed#programme__15)

Answer (score 0):

I believe **standardized** or **methodized** or **systematized**/**systemized** is the adjective you're looking for.

**standardized**

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/standardized)

> designed or constructed in a standard manner or according to an official standard

**methodized**

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/methodize)

> : [reduced] to a method

**systematized**

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/systematize)

> (full definition) : [arranged in accordance] with a definite plan or scheme

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

> ***[unidirectional](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unidirectional)***:
>
> not subject to change or reversal of direction